# Python: TaggedCorpusReader how to get from a STTS to a Universal tagset

Tags: python, keras, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm working on a POS Tagger using Python and Keras. The data I've got is using the STTS Tags, but I'm supposed to create a Tagger for the universal tagset. So I need to translate this.

First I thought of making a dictionary and simply search replace the tags, but then I saw the option of setting a tagset using the TaggedCorpusReader. (e.g. 'brown')

But I miss a list of possible tagsets that can be used there. Can I use the STTS Tagset somehow or do I have to make a dictionary myself?

**Example Source:**
Code #3 : map corpus tags to the universal tagset
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-customization-using-tagged-corpus-reader/

```
corpus = TaggedCorpusReader(filePath, "standard_pos_tagged.txt", tagset='STTS') #?? doesn't work sadly
# ....
trainingCorpus.tagged_sents(tagset='universal')[1]
```

---

**In the end it looked something like this:** (big thanks to [alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis))

```
with open(resultFileName, "w") as output:
    for sent in stts_corpus.tagged_sents():
        for word, tag in sent:
            try:
                newTag = mapping_dict[tag];
                output.write(word+"/"+newTag+" ")               
            except:
                print("except "  + str(word) + " - " + str(tag))
        output.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dictionary and replace the tags, as you considered doing. The nltk's universal tagset support is provided by the module `nltk/tag/mapping.py`. It relies on a set of mapping files, which you will find in `NLTK_DATA/taggers/universal_tagset`. For example, in `en-brown.map` you'll find lines like this, which map a whole bunch of tags to `PRT`, `ABX` to `DET`, and so on:

```
ABL     PRT
ABN     PRT
ABN-HL  PRT
ABN-NC  PRT
ABN-TL  PRT
ABX     DET
AP      ADJ
```

These files are read into a dictionary that is used for the translation. By creating a mapping file in the same format you could use the nltk's functions to perform the translation, but honestly if your task is simply to produce a corpus in the Universal format, I would just do the translation by hand. But not through "search-replace": Work with the tuples provided by the nltk's corpus readers, and just replace the POS tags by direct lookup in your mapping dictionary.

Let's assume you know how to persuade an nltk `TaggedCorpusReader` to read your corpus, and you now have an `stts_corpus` reader object with methods `tagged_words()`, `tagged_sents()`, etc. You also need the mapping dictionary, whose keys are STTS tags and values are universal tags; if `ABL` was an STTS tag, `mapping_dict["ABL"]` should return the value `PRT`. Your remapping then goes something like this:

```
for filename in stts_corpus.fileids():
    with open("new_dir/"+filename, "w") as output:
        for word, tag in stts_corpus.tagged_words():
            output.write(word+"/"+mapping_dict[tag]+" ")
        output.write("\n")
```

And that's really all there is to it, unless you want to add luxuries like breaking the text into lines.

Comment: Works perfectly. Although I had to use the luxury of new lines :)

Comment: For the record, there are two easy approaches to newlines: a) loop over `tagged_sents()` and output a newline after each sentence; or b) collect output into a string and run it through `textrwrap.fill()` before writing to a file.

Comment: I chose the first one. Looped over every tupple in tagged_sents and added a newline at the end. But the second one is new to me. Thanks for the input